# node.js / Https with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

I try to use express in `node.js` with `https`.

Here the relevant code for this parts:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./sslcert/mykey.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./sslcert/mssl.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(5008, function(res){
console.log("Listen to: " + port)
});
```

In the console, it prints `Listen to: 5008`, but I don't see that my server get any request, even though I sent some.

When I use express without the ssl extension, everything works fine.

**EDIT:**

Here the code which works OK with port 5008, but without the ssl part:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.listen(5008, function () {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Are you connecting via localhost? If not, do you allow incoming traffic on 5008 in your firewall/security software? Does it not connect at all or do you get an HTTP response?

Comment: @mscdex: The port is is open, and I don't connect via localhost (other machine call my server..). I added a code that works OK for me, but withput the ssl part. thanks.

Comment: and you are adding `https://` in front of the address when testing so it's `https://example.org:5008`?

Comment: @mscdex: No, https is for port 443, no? I check it with: `http://example.org:5008`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `https://`, otherwise the browser/client will not know to use SSL when connecting, no matter what port is used (the default of 443 or otherwise).

Comment: Thanks, when I use `https://example.org` it gives me the following error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake` (In my Java client)

Comment: No, I change it, and now My server listens to 443. Still it gives me this error..

Comment: It gives me the following:
`* About to connect() to <My host name> port 443 (#0)
*   Trying <The IP>... connected
...* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error`